# Trouble solving a Algoritm Problem - product of the sum of two sublists

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

everyone could someone hint me on how to solve this problem:

```
You're given a number y and a long list.
And you have to find 2 sublists in this long list (the longest possible) 
whose product of sum is equal to the given y number.

Exemple:

[3,6,7,2,10,1,4]
y = 476
sublist_1 = [3,6,7,2,10]
sublist_2 = [2,10,1,4]

Because 3+6+7+2+10 = 28
and 2+10+1+4 = 17
And 28x17=476
```

i've been thinking for quite a while now on this problem but i have no clue on where to start, could someone please give me a hint on where to start please

Comment: The brute force method.  Divide the list into two lists of N - 1 length.  Check the sum/product.  Divide the list into two lists of N - 1 length and three lists of N - 2 length.  Divide the list into two lists of N - 1 length and four lists of N - 3 length.   Repeat until you've checked all the sublists of length 2.

Comment: In your example, the two sublists correpond to adjacent elements. It is always the case?

Comment: no, not necesseraly